# Build java solution with 4 configurations in one call

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, swt

I have solution with 5 projects:

- 00-PROJECT - Parent project for whole solution. Other projects are submodeles of this one.
- 01-INTERFACE - API description library for communications between client and server
- 02-SERVER  - Server application that provides API
- 03-CLIENT - Client modules that communicate with server application
- 04-DESKTOP - Desktop application built using SWT GUI library. Communicates with server using client modules from 03-CLIENT.

While I develop this whole solution I need to have embedded `02-SERVER` in `04-DESKTOP`. This is needed to easy run and debug application in Eclipse IDE because both and client and server are under develop together.

But to deploy application to the client I need to build `02-SERVER` and `04-DESKTOP` separately. I found solution for prepare deployment .zip - it is `maven-assembly-plugin`. It assemblies all .jars, configuration files, jasper templates in one .zip (or folder). It works perfect. But one problem appeared when I tried to create deployment package of `04-DESKTOP` for several platforms, at least these three: Windows 32bit, Windows 64bit, Linux 64bit (all are used in customer's organization).

One of solutions for `04-DESKTOP` is profiles. Maven provide a powerful profiles system. But the problem was that you can run maven with one profile and there is no way to invoke maven for several profiles. The second think is wen I invoke maven to build packages for each profile using parent pom `02-SERVER` is recompiled each time and I didn't like this solution.

The my main question was **how prepare 5 packages (one server package and 4 desktop packages) with single command? e.g. invoke `mvn package` in parent project.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for answer for a while. Here are similar questions on stackoverflow.com and answers, but I didn't found answer for my question. After some research and tries I found solution.

I just added 4 projects in solution for each platform I needed. So my solution now has 7 projects:

- 00-PROJECT
- 01-INTERFACE
- 02-SERVER
- 03-CLIENT
- 04-DESKTOP
- **04-DESKTOP-LINUX-x86**
- **04-DESKTOP-LINUX-x64**
- **04-DESKTOP-WIN32-x86**
- **04-DESKTOP-WIN32-x64**

There are no source codes in folders in these additional projects. But there is `pom.xml` in these projects. The build configuration points to `04-DESKTOP` sources folder:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>../04-DESKTOP/src</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Because all these 4 projects are modules in main project I can't give them the same `artifactId`. But `maven-jar-plugin` by default creates jar with name equals to artifactId. So result jar file name is redefined in `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix></classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>net.cloudstock.desktop.app</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>net.cloudstock.desktop-${project.version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The whole `pom.xml` for one of additional projects is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Information about parent project -->
        <artifactId>net.cloudstock.system</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.cloudstock</groupId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>net.cloudstock.desktop.win32.x86</artifactId>
    <name>Cloudstock Descktop frontend (Windows x86)</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Operation system where this app must run -->
        <os>win32</os>
        <!-- Processor architecture -->
        <arch>x86</arch>
        <!-- Variable to point sources to 04-DESKTOP/src folder -->
        <desktop.root>../04-DESKTOP</desktop.root>
        <!-- I am new in maven, so I can't comment this line -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <!-- Tell to the compiler where sources are -->
        <sourceDirectory>${desktop.root}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix></classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>net.cloudstock.desktop.app</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                            <!-- Redefine result jar, because by default its name will be net.cloudstock.desktop.win32.x86-{VERSION}.jar -->

                    <finalName>net.cloudstock.desktop-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>${desktop.root}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                                    <!-- the name of the zip archive with program that I send to the customer --> 
                            <finalName>net.cloudstock.desktop-${os}-${arch}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- SWT for Win x86. It differs for different OSes and processors -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Other application deps. They are duplicated in all 04-DESKTOP* projects --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.cloudstock</groupId>
            <artifactId>net.cloudstock.client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.cloudstock</groupId>
            <artifactId>net.cloudstock.interface</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jface</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jface</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.v20120521-2329</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The one thing in this schema is not enough nice is a hack in `${desktop.root}/assembly.xml`
You can't tell to maven-assembly-plugin to include artifact jar in assembly because it includes jar with artifactId name. So I added one additional `fileSet` to include resulting jar from current project:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>lib/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>net.cloudstock.desktop-${project.version}.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    ...
</fileSets>
```

An the end I added dependency tag in `04-DESCTOP/pom.xml` to include `02-SERVER` and four profiles witch are activated by os condition:

```
<profile>
    <id>win-x86-debug</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <os>
            <family>Windows</family>
            <arch>x86</arch>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Now I develop desktop application in `04-DESCTOP` project in Eclipse. I can run and debug whole solution.

When I finish with current iteration and want to send application to the customer I build it using one command from parent project `mvn package`:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cloudstock System ..................................... SUCCESS [2.202s]
[INFO] Helper Library by Nicolai Budico ...................... SUCCESS [4.563s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Interface .................................. SUCCESS [2.925s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Server ..................................... SUCCESS [3.835s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Client Backend ............................. SUCCESS [1.120s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Descktop frontend (Windows x86) ............ SUCCESS [9.019s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Descktop frontend (Windows x64) ............ SUCCESS [5.530s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Descktop frontend (Linux x86) .............. SUCCESS [5.158s]
[INFO] Cloudstock Descktop frontend (Linux x64) .............. SUCCESS [4.998s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The last think that must be noticed in this solution is that You need to edit 5 pom's if something is changed in desktop application configuration.

Maybe this solution is wrong, maybe it is not so correct, but I am very happy with it. And I really hope this will be helpful for someone.